# QGIS 1.8 Vector layer from ODBC connection

Tags: qgis, odbc

I have successfully set up an ODBC link from a FileMaker DB to QGIS, and using Layer/Add Vector Layer I can get a layer with a fully populated attribute table listed in the Layers Panel.

I now want to plot datapoints from the new layer but cannot work out how to tell QGIS that the new layer has georeferenced information and which fields contain the LAT/LONG data.  I guess that I am expecting to find a window similar to that which appears when you create a layer from a Tab Delimited file, where you define which fields contain the LAT/LONG data.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can view location information via the attribute table if your data-set came with it. Otherwise you can go to your attribute table, click on the abacus icon (field calculator) and choose geometry. Then select $x and create a column for it and do the same with $y.